# How do you handle recursive dependencies in CMake

Tags: cmake

Say I have packages A, B, and C. Package B uses package A and package C uses package B. I create shared libraries.

So in package B I do something like

```
    find_package(A)
    ...
    if(${A_FOUND})
    target_link_libraries(B ${A_LIBRARIES})
    endif()
```

and in package C I do

```
    find_package(B)
    ...
    if(${B_FOUND})
    target_link_libraries(C ${B_LIBRARIES})
    endif()

    add_executable(main main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(main C)
```

where ${B_LIBRARIES} contains only B. The compiler will now complain

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lA
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

as long as A is installed in a place that is not in the link_directories of C. I was wondering what is the correct way of handling this. For me using `find_package(A)` in C (which would work) doesn't seem to be the nice. For me especially, because I don't know in advance if B depends on A or not. It might also depend on a different package.

Comment: `find_package(A)` usually define variable with name like `A_LIBRARIES`, which should be used for link executable/libraries with A: `target_link_libraries(B ${A_LIBRARIES})`. See description of script `FindA.cmake` for concrete `A`.

Comment: This is actually what I do here, since `${A_LIBRARIES}` would just contain `A`. Sorry if that was unclear. But then still the same problem arises, because `${B_LIBRARIES}` does not contain `A`. At least I have never seen any project that includes all of its dependencies in `${A_LIBRARIES}` and `${A_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}` etc. Should I do this anyway?

Comment: `${A_LIBRARIES}` should contain **absolute path** to the library A, so linker will be able to find it even without setup of `link_directories`. Likewise, `${B_LIBRARIES}` should contain **absolute paths** to both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes, so that's basically what my question is about. Should I actually put `${A_LIBRARIES}` in `${B_LIBRARIES}`? I have never seen any project that does this. Do you have an example where they do this? To me it seemed like this could not be the "right" way. It made more sense to me if `${B_LIBRARIES}` only contained libraries that are part of B.

Comment: Actually, because it's a shared library, C already tries to link to A. That's where the problem lies. For this, I didn't do anything special. I just did `target_link_libraries(B ${A_LIBRARIES})` after which CMake makes sure it tries to link to A in C. Do I have to force CMake to use absolute paths or something?

Comment: If you want library `B` be able to be linked alone, without noticing of `A`, it should be **loadable** alone: `ldd B` should resolve all libraries. E.g., `B` may use `RPATH`, contained path to `A`. BTW, how did you get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lA` if link list for `C` doesn't contain A *directly*?

Comment: A, B and C are all built as a shared library, so even if ${B_LIBRARIES} only contains B, C will still try to link to A.

Anyhow,  found my problem. In my case A is Trilinos, and Trilinos supplies something called Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS, which gives you the directories you have to include in link_directories. I found in the documentation that this is wrong and that the libraries itself should be absolute paths. I'll provide my solution in an answer below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I still don't fully understand this, because https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file tells me to do `set(FOOBAR_LIBRARIES foo)` which does not contain absolute paths...

Comment: Carefully read comment before this assignment: `# These are IMPORTED targets created by FooBarTargets.cmake`. `foo` here is not a library name, but a library **target**. The target itself contains full path to the library file. Note, that intention of `*Config.cmake` script differs from one of `Find*.cmake` one.

Comment: Yes, but if I use this target `A` in `${A_LIBRARIES}`, `B` will compile just fine and the linker will show that it compiles with absolute paths, but then when I try to build `C`, it will again complain that `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lA`. `find_package(A)` will first try to find `FindA.cmake` and then `AConfig.cmake`, and according to the `link_libraries` documentation "Library locations returned by find_package() and find_library() are absolute paths." But apparently in the case `AConfig.cmake` is used where the config file was created as described in the tutorial this does not hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `${A_LIBRARIES}` should contain absolute paths. Packages like Trilinos provide something like `${Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS}`, which you should include in by doing

```
link_directories(${Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

This, however, is wrong according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html . `find_package(Trilinos)` should return absolute paths to the libraries, so I should not have to do this. I fixed this by doing something like

```
set(library_directories ${Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS})
list(APPEND library_directories ${Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(library_dependencies ${Trilinos_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND library_dependencies ${Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARIES})

set(found_library_dependencies)
foreach(lib ${library_dependencies})
  set(found_${lib})
  if(IS_ABSOLUTE ${lib})
    set(found_${lib} ${lib})
  else()
    find_library(found_${lib} ${lib} ${library_directories})
  endif()
  list(APPEND found_library_dependencies ${found_${lib}})
  message(STATUS "Using ${lib}")
  message(STATUS "Found in ${found_${lib}}")
endforeach(lib)
```

I made a list of the packages here so I can do this for all my packages which all copied this wrong behaviour from Trilinos.

Coming back on the original problem. I do still have to include the `${A_INCLUDE_DIRS}` in `${B_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, so `C` can find the header files of `A` that are included in header files of `B`, but I can live with this. However, `${B_LIBRARIES}` now does not have to include `${A_LIBRARIES}`, since they were built as shared libraries. And that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to make each library export its targets by creating a "proper" configuration file. This is kind of documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-a-package-configuration-file), but basically for every `find_package()` call you're supposed to add a corresponding `find_dependency()` call into your configuration file. When you do this, the targets will be recursively found as cmake packages, and all transitive dependencies should be included.

Here is an example of what I mean:

### Project A

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(liba)
add_library(a src/a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(a PUBLIC flag1 flag2)
install(TARGETS a EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

`libaConfig.cmake`:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libaTargets.cmake")
```

### Project B

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(libb)
add_library(b src/b.cpp)
find_package(liba CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(b PUBLIC a)
install(TARGETS b EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

`libbConfig.cmake`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(liba) # The key step for getting recursion working
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libbTargets.cmake")
```

### Project C

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(libb CONFIG REQUIRED) # Also recursively calls find_package(liba ...)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE b) # should become -lb -la -lflag1 -lflag2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `find_package` because with that you are telling the compiler to look for a package already installed in the users machine. Instead first create the libraries with `add_library` and later in your binary you can include the header directory with `include_directories` the rest is known.

Comment: They are different packages and they are installed on the system. At least in a place where CMake can find them. So `${A_FOUND}` and `${B_FOUND}` would both be true.

Comment: Are they true, then?

Comment: Yes. I'll adjust the example in my question a bit so I actually use this. I just didn't want to make it too much of a mess.