# CMake multiple libraries in different repositories

Tags: c++, cmake

### Introduction

For the last couple of months I have been working on a project consisting of a number of repositories (and there will be more and more repositories as time goes by). Each repository is part of a bigger framework, where one of the repository can depend on any number of the other repositories. Since they are all part of the same framework I would like them to be `COMPONENTS` of a common CMake namespace. I would also like the user to only have to clone the repositories (and their dependencies) that the user is interested in.

I am new to CMake and have been trying to get this working, on and off, for the last couple of months without much success. I have read and watched a number of talks about "Modern CMake" and searched different forums without any luck. Therefore I hope someone here can help me or at least point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated!

### Short Example

I will now present a short example to make it more clear what I am looking for.

Imagine that we have these repositories:

1. Rep1 does not depend on any other repository
2. Rep2 depends on Rep1
3. Rep3 depends on Rep1 and Rep2
4. Rep4 depends on Rep3
5. ...

If the user is only interested in Rep2. Then it should be possible to only clone Rep1 and Rep2.

For this I would like to be able to do this:

- For Rep2 call `find_package(COMMON_NAMESPACE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Rep1)` and then `target_link_libraries`
- For Rep3 call `find_package(COMMON_NAMESPACE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Rep1 Rep2)` and then `target_link_libraries`
- For Rep4 call `find_package(COMMON_NAMESPACE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Rep3)` and then `target_link_libraries`

However, I do not know how to get COMPONENTS working when having different repositories for the different COMPONENTS. It is **not** an alternative to have a common top-level `CMakeLists.txt` which `add_subdirectory` is called in for each repository, since I want people to be able to clone each repository separately however they want. If someone knows how to achieve this I would be very grateful if you could explain it to me!

### What I Have Now

For now I am instead just trying to solve it like this:

1. For Rep2 call `find_package(Rep1 REQUIRED)` and then `target_link_libraries(Rep2 PUBLIC COMMON_NAMESPACE::Rep1)`
2. For Rep3 call `find_package(Rep1 REQUIRED)`, `find_package(Rep2 REQUIRED)` and then `target_link_libraries(Rep3 PUBLIC COMMON_NAMESPACE::Rep1 COMMON_NAMESPACE::Rep2)`
3. For Rep4 call `find_package(Rep3 REQUIRED)` and then `target_link_libraries(Rep4 PUBLIC COMMON_NAMESPACE::Rep3)`

The first two works. But with the third I get:

```
Target "Rep4" links to target "COMMON_NAMESPACE::Rep1" but the target was not found.
Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
ALIAS target is missing?
```

How can this be solved without calling `find_package(Rep1 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(Rep2 REQUIRED)` in Rep4?

### Current File Structure

Here is an outline of the file structure. "Example" is the common namespace I would like to use:

- Rep1

  - cmake

    - Rep1_ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  - include

    - Example

      - Rep1

        - some_header.h
  - src

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - some_cpp.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- Rep2

  - cmake

    - Rep2_ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  - include

    - Example

      - Rep2

        - some_header.h
  - src

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - some_cpp.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- Rep3

  - cmake

    - Rep3_ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  - include

    - Example

      - Rep3

        - some_header.h
  - src

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - some_cpp.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- Rep4

  - cmake

    - Rep4_ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  - include

    - Example

      - Rep4

        - some_header.h
  - src

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - some_cpp.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- ...

### Current CMake File Content

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file for each repository looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(RepX_Project 
    VERSION 1.0 
    DESCRIPTION "RepX_Project ..."
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file located in `src` for each repository looks like this:

```
# The namespace used
set(NS Example)

set(HEADER_LIST
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${NS}/RepX/some_header.h"
    ...
)

set(SRC_LIST
    some_cpp.cpp
    ...
)

# Some of them might depend on one (or more) of the other repositories
find_package(RepY REQUIRED)
...

add_library(RepX SHARED ${SRC_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})
add_library(${NS}::RepX ALIAS RepX)

set_target_properties(RepX
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${RepX_Project_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${RepX_Project_SOVERSION}
        CXX_STANDARD 17
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

target_include_directories(RepX 
    PUBLIC 
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)

# If this repository depends on one (or more) of the other repositories
target_link_libraries(RepX 
    PUBLIC 
        ${NS}::RepY
        ...
)

target_compile_features(RepX PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

source_group(TREE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" PREFIX "Header Files" FILES ${HEADER_LIST})

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

configure_package_config_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION ${PACKAGE_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

install(TARGETS RepX 
    EXPORT RepXTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

install(EXPORT RepXTargets
    FILE 
        RepXTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE 
        ${NS}::
    DESTINATION 
        lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(FILES 
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"   
    DESTINATION 
        lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
                
install(DIRECTORY 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ 
    DESTINATION 
        include
)
```

The `.cmake.in` file for each repository looks like this:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/RepXTargets.cmake")
check_required_components("RepX")
```

### Questions

1. How to use `COMPONENTS` when the different components is in their own repository?
2. What do I have to fix in order for `find_package` to be able to recursively find all my dependencies?
3. How to handle CMake namespaces correctly?

   - Currently I have to create a COMMON_NAMESPACE folder in each include directory for each repository. Also, in the `.cmake.in` I have to hardcode the target name for each library in each repository for this to work.
4. Is my `.cmake.in` file correct? Should I create my own CMake config file also?
5. Can I improve the `CMakeLists.txt` files located in the `src` directories?

### Last Note

I really appreciate you taking your time to read this and (hopefully) help me with this. Sorry that this post is so long, I tried being as concise as possible while at the same time showing everything I have in order for you to get the complete picture. Just ask if there is any other information that you would want in order to better/easier help with this, I am happy to provide any additional information that you might need! Hopefully this can help other people as well.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: You might be better off using a package manager, e.g https://conan.io/ rather than trying to do it all in cmake

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you! I have never used [conan.io](https://conan.io/) but I will take a look at it.

Comment: Update: I managed to solve the problem I have with my current approach (described under "What I Have Now" and question 2)  with this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929353/3459090](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929353/3459090).